# What happened to the test@domain.tld syntax?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registrar

I can remember that some years ago several providers advertised the possibility to use the @ syntax instead of general subdomains with their DNS service. Today, I can't find any documentation or hints about this anymore, besides Google Chrome asking me whether I wanted to open `http://test@domain.tld` when entering the possible email address (without the protocol) in the search bar. What happened to this domain syntax?

Comment: I can remember that 1&1 used to offer these '@' domains. Basically ended up being an alias to a subdirectory and rather pointless...

Comment: That's what I was talking about. Now that you call it I remember it being called "@ domain alias".
Well, I guess that means there is no DNS syntax that has been used, just a webserver based redirection. Thanks for your help, I guess that question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ has a special meaning, when used in a URL. Here's a URL with everything possible in it:

```
scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

The @ separates the password from the domain. So I think you're remembering something else.

Comment: Well, maybe I do remember wrong. I know about the possibility to provide authentification information in the URL, but thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: I also only remember ever using @'s in URLs for auth purposes. It still works, if supported(eg. used to be possible for Twitter's feeds until NewTwitter), but overall has long-since largely fallen out of favor. I don't recall it ever being too common in the first place.

Comment: The reason it fell out of favour was because of a lot of phishing scams of the form "http://passwordreset.microsoft.com/reset.aspx?code=sandlewood/counternanny@banditry.cx/9309823652308f09838" actually being a username link to banditry.cx